# Java: How to open logfile via RestFulWebServer

Tags: java, server, logfile

I would like to know how to use `@Getmapping("/logFile")` 
to open the last logfile that I created?

Situation: I upload a file to my server and my server runs a (.bat) and the outcome of this bat is converted into a jogfile. I want to create a button in my gui that allows me to push it and opens this for me. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Write a servlet that opens a textfile and puts the file content into response object.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normals Java methods File, FileReader, StringBuilder:

```
  File file = new File("logfile.txt");

  // Creates a FileReader Object
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
  char [] a = new char[...];
  fr.read(a);   // reads the content to the array
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  for(char c : a)
     result.append(c);  //Or you find a way to read strings
  fr.close();
```

Then you just return the result of the StringBuilder. Of course that you would need to find a way to pretty print the log file.